# Python Find max value in 2 element list

Tags: python, list

I have a 2 elements list like this one:

```
[(0, 0.020449258), (1, 0.020540833), (2, 0.35077244), (3, 0.5467364), (4, 0.020515079), (5, 0.020485992), (6, 0.020499969)]
```

My goal is to fix the max value in the second column and return the first one.
So as per example I should be able to return 3 as it got the max value (0.5467364)

I'm able to find the max value using this code (where "result" is the list above):

```
max_value = max(l[1] for l in result)
```

I'm struggling to get the index of such element to return the value =>3, I tryed:

```
max_index = result.index(max_value)
```

and is returning this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thx

Comment: You could pass a `key` argument to `max`: `max(l, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
arr = [
    (0, 0.020449258), 
    (1, 0.020540833), 
    (2, 0.35077244), 
    (3, 0.5467364), 
    (4, 0.020515079), 
    (5, 0.020485992), 
    (6, 0.020499969)
]
# sort the array based on the second element
arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# get the first element of the sorted array
print(arr[0][0])
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: The sort can be time-consuming for long lists.

Comment: I don't think this should be an accepted answer as it needlessly sorts the list.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity O(n)

```py
a = [(0, 0.020449258), (1, 0.020540833), (2, 0.35077244), (3, 0.5467364),
     (4, 0.020515079), (5, 0.020485992), (6, 0.020499969)]

value = (0, 0)
for i in a:
    if i[1] > value[1]:
        value = i
print(value)  # --> (3, 0.5467364)
# or print value[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer could be:

```
list = [(0, 0.020449258), (1, 0.020540833), (2, 0.35077244), (3, 0.5467364), (4, 0.020515079), (5, 0.020485992), (6, 0.020499969)]
max_index = 0
max_value = list[0][1]
for index in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[index][1] > max_value:
        max_value = list[index][1]
        max_index = index
print(max_index, max_value)
```

Comment: It's better not to use built-in names as your variables' name.

Comment: It's important that this code is tested and works. But thanks for your advice. @SorousHBakhtiary

Answer (score 0):

You could use **list comprehension** and **numpy.argmax** to break it down to 4 lines as follows:

**(Just comment/remove the optional second line if sorting is not needed as it'll take time to sort longer lists.)**

```py
data_list = [(0, 0.020449258), (1, 0.020540833), (2, 0.35077244), (3, 0.5467364), (4, 0.020515079), (5, 0.020485992), (6, 0.020499969)]

# Optional
data_list.sort()   # The tuples are now sorted accordingly
# Optional

values_list = [i[1] for i in data_list]            # List of the second elements
max_index = numpy.argmax(values_list)              # Index of max tuple
max_first_element = data_list[max_index][0]        # First element in that max tuple

print(max_first_element)
```

Or a **one liner version** would be :

```py
max_first_element = data_list[numpy.argmax([i[1] for i in data_list])][0]
```

**Please dont forget to import numpy at the top!**

Comment: It's better not to use built-in names as your variables' name.

Comment: @SorousH very right, let me update.